# Where would one start learning how to make a moderator bot/banlist program for starcraft 2?

Tags: automation, social-gaming

Tried searching in various ways, could only really find one old result that was even close to what I was looking for and there was no "next-step" for that question. What I am thinking of would be similar to the old WC3Banlist (which I also tried to search about as a place to start learning about this, but as this was long ago the results were not enough to continue). I am no CS major, although I am fairly familiar with Python, R, and Java, my experience has mostly been in the automation/analytical areas, and this would be new ground for me. I see this as a fun side-project to learn, while helping a gaming community, I just cannot figure out where I should start learning and building such a program. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

I tried various google-searches to find a place to start my research, and only found one related result, which did not render any helpful hints or clues.